# WPF DataGrid disable cell edit based on value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF `DataGrid` populated with an `ObservableCollection<ZeroConnection>` named `ZeroTable`. If `ZeroTable.NetID == 0` the `DataGrid` row should be disabled and that works. Furthermore if `ZeroTable.Number == ""` editing of that particular cell should be disabled. But have not succeeded to implement this as the user still can edit the cell. My XAML below;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local2:RowReadOnlyConverter x:Key="RowReadOnlyConverter" />
    <local2:CellReadOnlyConverter x:Key="CellReadOnlyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="ZeroTableGridView" Grid.Column="0"  AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEEEEEE" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ZeroTable}"  CanUserAddRows="False"
          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"  dd:DragDrop.DropTargetAdornerBrush="Coral" 
          dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding }">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NetID, Converter={StaticResource RowReadOnlyConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nummer" Binding="{Binding Number}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource CellReadOnlyConverter}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink"/> <!-- For debugging -->
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ledning" Binding="{Binding Wire}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postbeteckning" Binding="{Binding ItemDes}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Uttag" Binding="{Binding Terminal}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hänvisning" Binding="{Binding Ref}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kretsschema" Binding="{Binding Sheet}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anmärkning" Binding="{Binding Remark}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding NetID}" CanUserSort="False"/> -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the C# code below;

```
public class CellReadOnlyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string number = (string)value;
        if (number == "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}

public class RowReadOnlyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int netID = (int) value;
        if (netID == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

The cell "number" that contains an empty string is still editable. The background of the cell does change so the `DataTrigger` seems to be activated. Help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to use `TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"`instead?

Comment: You don't edit a textblock, you edit a textbox. And you want editingelementstyle rather than elementstyle.

Comment: Thanks. Changing to ``TextBox`` and ``EditingElementStyle`` was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need EditingElementStyle to mark the field enabled/disabled

Code below shows how to do it

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Nummer" Binding="{Binding Number}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```